# Como calcular el años para fechas anteriores en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Compañeros Tengo un SQL en el cual puedo calcular la fecha apartir de mi fecha en el sistema.

Con lo anterior necesito integrar una funcion donde pueda calcular la fecha a partir de una fecha determinada por mi.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
SELECT
    a.Id_Tercero,
    A.Codigo_Afiliado AS Codigo_Anterior,
    UPPER(b.Nombre_Comercial_Protocolo) AS Nombre_Comercial,
    UPPER(b.Razon_Social_Protocolo) AS Razon_Social,
    d.Descripcion AS Ciudad,
    c.Direccion,
    e.Numero_Telefono AS Telefono1,
    e.Numero_Telefono AS Fax,
    a.Fecha_Afiliacion,
    DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Tiempo_Afiliacion,
```

Detemina la los campos involucrados; se condiciona algunos facturos para el resultado.

```
    a.Tipo_Afiliacion,
    g.Id_Regional+' - '+g.Nombre AS Regional,
    --h.Codigo_Zona + ' - ' + h.Descripcion AS Zona,
    b.Nombre_Completo_Representante_Legal,
    b.genero_representante_legal,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.Estado = '1' THEN 'Activo'
        WHEN a.Estado = '2' THEN 'Suspendido'
        WHEN a.Estado = '3' THEN 'Retirado'
    END AS Estado
FROM dbo.M_Terceros_Mae_Terceros_Info_Afiliacion a
    INNER JOIN dbo.M_Terceros_Mae_Terceros b ON a.Id_Tercero = b.Id_Tercero
    INNER JOIN dbo.M_Ubicaciones_Mov_Terceros_Direcciones c ON a.Id_Tercero = c.Id_Tercero AND c.Id_Clase_Direccion = '3'
    --INNER JOIN dbo.M_Ubicaciones_Conf_Zonas_Ubicacion H ON c.Id_Zona = H.Id_Zona
    INNER JOIN dbo.M_Ubicaciones_Conf_Ciudades d ON c.Id_Ciudad = d.Id_Ciudad
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.M_Ubicaciones_Mov_Terceros_Telefonos WHERE Id_Tercero = a.Id_Tercero AND Principal = '1'
    )e
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.M_Ubicaciones_Mov_Terceros_Telefonos WHERE Id_Tercero = a.Id_Tercero AND Id_Telefono_Tipo = '2'
    )f
    INNER JOIN dbo.Conf_Regionales_Fenalco g ON a.Id_Regional_Ubicacion = g.Id_Regional
WHERE
(
```

Determina el rango de tiempo a partir de quinqueños, que son intervalos de 5 años.

```
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=5 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=10 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=15 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=20 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=25 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=30 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=35 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=40 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=45 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=50 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=55 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=60 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=65 OR
DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=70 --OR
--DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=75 --OR
--DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=80   
)
and dateadd(year, -1, ge )
--AND MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion))in ('01','02','03','04','05','06')
--AND MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion))in ('07','08','09','10','11','12')
--AND MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion))in ('07','08','09')
AND a.Estado in ('1','2')
AND a.Tipo_Afiliacion IN ('C','P')
/*AND a.Id_Regional_Ubicacion IN ('1','2','3')
AND a.Id_Seccional_Afiliacion = '1' --Solo antioquia*/
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(year, CONVERT(DATETIME,a.Fecha_Afiliacion)  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

PD: Tengo conocimiento de que la función `DATEADD` se puede utilizar para `SQL SERVER` Pero no se como implementarlo.

Comment: creo que este es un caso en el que mostrar un ejemplo de los resultados que quieres sería mejor...por lo menos en mi caso, no entiendo la pregunta

Comment: Entiendo... En esta consulta el resultado el que calcula un tipo de aniversario cada 5, 10, 15, 20 ... años

Comment: Bienvenido Jhonatan Cardona Giraldo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Estoy igual que Lamak, no entiendo mu bien que es lo que preguntas, ¿Quieres calcular años hacia atrás a partir de una fecha? pro ejemplo: `select dateadd(year, -15, getdate())`?

Comment: Entiendo que quieres mostrar datos de un trimestre cualquiera de años anteriores. Por ejemplo, entre enero y marzo del año 2017. Corrígeme si estoy errado, por favor.

Comment: Si, Necesito consultar fechas anteriores, relacionando ampos de diferentes tablas y haciendo calculos entre 5 años de cumplimiento